# How to manage Debian source with Chef?

Tags: debian, chef-infra, apt

I would like to add contrib and non-free components to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I found this Cookbook https://github.com/reaktor/chef-debian but it does not seems to be maintained anymore.

Is there any alternative better than using `template` and rewrite the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just use the `apt_repository` resource, see https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_repository.html

If you're using an older chef-client version (pre 12.9), you'll have to add the `apt` cookbook from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apt